# How to click on the list item using selenium driver in Python3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have the following HTML code

```
<ul id="vmStateDropDown" class="dropdown-content active" style="white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 83px; left: 264px; opacity: 1; display: block;"><li class="waves-effect waves-default" style="display: block;"><a class="" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons left" style="cursor: pointer;">directions_run</i><span>Turn On</span></a></li><li class="waves-effect waves-default" style="display: block;"><a class="disabled" disabled="" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons left" style="cursor: pointer;">power_settings_new</i><span>Turn Off</span></a></li><li class="waves-effect waves-default" style="display: block;"><a class="disabled" disabled="" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons left" style="cursor: pointer;">loop</i><span>Restart</span></a></li></ul>
```

I need to click in the list item **Turn On**. Here is the code I have so far.

```
turn_vmon = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[4]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
```

When I print the text for turn_vmon variable, I can see the option which I need. However I am unable to figure out how to click on the list item.

Can someone please help?

Comment: you use .click() to click when you print turn_vmon out what do you get?

Comment: @AndrewRyan

This is what I get when I print turn_vmon

`[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="af81df22b1a050a43cb5513921afded2", element="4a9f444b-b779-4525-b9c0-3490e7677121")>]`

When I print `turn_vmon[0].text`

`directions_run
Turn On`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as ***Turn On*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Turn On']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Turn On']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you. The xpath option worked out. I think I have to figure out how to properly navigate elements.